# Writing to closed TCP/IP connection hangs

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

My TCP/IP client hangs while writing to socket. This happens even if server properly closes an accepted connection with `close()` (or with `shutdown()`) call. I've always thought that write should return with ECONNRESET error for this case.

How do i prevent hang ups in synchronous output? Or rather what am I doing wrong so that an error is not reported by `write()`?

Should I use `send()` instead of `write()` or they are interchangeable?

I'm testing networking in a separate application with two threads.
Main thread starts server thread, that accepts connection and immediately closes it. Main thread then imitates client behavior by connecting to listening port.

Main thread code:

```
sockaddr_in serv_addr;
bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (bind(s, (sockaddr*)(&serv_addr),  sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
    close(s);
    throw runtime_error(strerror(errno));
}
listen(s,1);
start_thread(s); // posix thread accepting a connection on s is started here
//Code below imitates  TCP/IP client
struct hostent *hp;
struct sockaddr_in addr;
if((hp = gethostbyname(host.c_str())) == NULL){
    throw HErrno();
}
bcopy(hp->h_addr, &addr.sin_addr, hp->h_length);
addr.sin_port = htons(port);
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
int _socket = ::socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (_socket < 0) {
    throw Errno();
}
assert(ENOTCONN==107);
assert(_socket>=0);
if(::connect(_socket, (const struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1){
    throw Errno();
}

while(true) {
  const char a[] = "pattern";
  if (write( _socket, a, 7)<0) // Writes 30000 times, then hangs
     break;
}
```

Server thread code:

```
int connection = accept(s);
close(connection);
```

**EDIT:**
The problem reduced to my programming error. It seems I've failed to start accepting thread properly.

Comment: How are you ensuring that when you client tries to connect, server has already started listening?

Comment: @fayyazkl, there is a listen call before accepting thread start. Accept call is successfull and returns readable fd.

Comment: @fayyazkl If that was the problem he wouldn't get a connection let alone a write() stall.

Answer (score 1):

Each TCP connection has a receive buffer for storing data that are received but not delivered to application. If in your server you don't do read(), than the data is accumulated in receive buffer, and at one point this receive buffer becomes full, causing TCP sends Window=0 message.

Your server thread code should look like this:

```
char a[10];
int connection = accept(s);
while(true)
    if (read( connection , a, 7)<=0)
        break;
close(connection);
```

Comment: This will hang forever if client never writes in the forever opened connection. How do I terminate connection without reading? And why `close()` does not free all buffers of this connection instance?

Comment: 1) If your client does a close(), than it's ok. The read() is returning 0 and the loop closes.
2) Of course with close(), but you do a close(), after all writes are finished.
3) close() frees all buffers at receives side, but it can't control the sender side.

Comment: 1) Obviously in real application server will have no control on what client does. It therefore meaningless to rely on client's behavior. 2) Same here - client does the writes, not the server. We can't reliably predict when all writes are done. 3)Then why TCP/IP on the clients side continues to receive acks and reports no errors?

Comment: @Basilevs It will also hang forever if the client never closes his socket. The solution to that is threefold: (1) write something, (2) close the socket, and (3) use a read timeout at the reading end.

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps set up a handler for `SIGPIPE` instead of setting it to `SIG_IGN`?